# Hay forma de acortar esto o de hacerlo en forma más prolija?

Tags: python

estoy intentando hacer el juego del ahorcado en python solo por práctica, hice una función que cambia las letras con acentos, diéresis y la ñ, hay forma de acortarla o hacerlo más prolijo?:

```
palabra = palabra.replace("Á", "A")
palabra = palabra.replace("É", "E")
palabra = palabra.replace("Í", "I")
palabra = palabra.replace("Ó", "O")
palabra = palabra.replace("Ú", "U")
palabra = palabra.replace("Ü", "U")
palabra = palabra.replace("Ñ", "N") # Cambia la letra Ñ
return palabra
```

Comment: Cual es el objetivo en especifico? Cambiar solo esas letras o remover cualquier carácter especial?

Comment: Cambiar solo esas letras

Comment: `palabra.translate(str.maketrans("ÁÉÍÓÚÑ", "AEIOUN"))`

Comment: Por cierto, querrás decir "menos prolija" :-) (o más concisa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo sin tener que crear un diccionario para cada caso que quieres es mediante [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/):

```
from unidecode import unidecode

antes = 'aáäAÁÄeéëEÉËiíïIÍÏoóöOÓÖuúüUÚÜñÑ'
despues = unidecode(antes)

print(despues)
```

Esto te devolverá:

```
aaaAAAeeeEEEiiiIIIoooOOOuuuUUUnN
```

La función `unidecode()` representa cualquier cadena Unicode en la representación más cercana posible en texto ASCII, de los caracteres imprimibles (puedes consultar los caracteres imprimibles en la [tabla ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/)).

Podría servir para el propósito de la pregunta, pero teniendo en cuenta que habrá ciertos caracteres que podrían verse transformados involuntariamente, como por ejemplo: `ª` -> `a`, `®` -> `(r)`, `©` -> `(c)`, `µ` -> `u`. Hay más, pero con estos se puede hacer uno a la idea de qué tipo de caracteres podrían cambiar.

Esta función se utiliza más para crear URLs válidas, pero dependiendo del caso, puede valer para eliminar tildes, diéresis o la virgulilla.

Comment: Sería estupendo que explicaras que es la función 'unidecode' y que otros usos tiene.

Comment: Unicode es un estándar de codificación que eventualmente tiene "caracteres especiales" que no se encuentran en otros estándares y al mostrarlos se verán de una forma poco ortodoxa.
Lo que hace ````unicode()````  es tomar estos datos y representarlos en ASCII.

En este caso la persona no quería transformar todos los caracteres, solo los que el definiera.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un diccionario donde la clave sea el valor a buscar y el contenido el valor a reemplazar, luego iterar el diccionario y ejecutar el método `.replace()`.

```
change = {"Á" : "A", "É" : "E", "Í" : "I", "Ó" : "O", "Ú" : "U", "Ü" : "U", "Ñ" : "N"}
word = "HOLÁ"
for search, value in change.items():
    word = word.replace(search, value)
print(word)
```

**UPDATE:**

Otra alternativa más limpia obtenida desde los comentarios, para que no se pierda.

```
word = word.translate(str.maketrans("ÁÉÍÓÚÑ", "AEIOUN"))
```

Comment: Dale ya lo pruebo, gracias.